# Convert flat JSON structure to table

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

Want to transform, by query, a column that looks like this

```
flat_json (one record) = {"a": 1, "b": "banana", "c": 3.14}
```

into a table structure like this

```
+---+--------+------+
| a | b      | c    |
+---+--------+------+
| 1 | banana | 3.14 |
+---+--------+------+
| 2 | beans  | 2.72 |
+---+--------+------+
```

So that I can just "unbox" it with other fields associated with the same record. I don't necessarily know the json field names. If I call this function "unbox" I'm looking for something akin to

`select * from unbox(flat_json)`

I've tried this style

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT  '{"a": 1, "b": "banana", "c": 3.14}'
    AS flat_json
)
SELECT
  json_extract(blob, '$.*')
FROM flat_json
```

and variants which error out on invalid JSON path. But using the same syntax I can pull single elements.

This other way seems like it may work with another step but is so complicated for the purpose.

```
WITH flat_json AS (
  SELECT  '{"a": 1, "b": "banana", "c": 3.14}' as flat_json
)
SELECT
  cast(json_parse(flat_json) as map<varchar, json>)

FROM flat_json
```

Output:

```
+---------------------------+
| flat_json                 |
+---------------------------+
| {a=1, b="banana", c=3.14} |
+---------------------------+
```

This will be a query on large data sets so I need it to be efficient as well. Thanks.

Comment: What I've seen so far requires explicitly referencing field names. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html. Try using `blob` in place of the first `flat_json` in the first style.

Comment: No. It doesn't address how to pull all key-values into row-like data without knowing the names of the fields beforehand and explicitly listing them off one by one. I want something equivalent to the JSON path `$.*`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no support for wildcards for Presto:

https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/7005